# User Input not being stored in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner in php and i just made a base64 encoder and decoder in php. It work's fine but I wanted all the hashes that the user tries out to be stored in a database. It doesn't show any syntax errors and i can'st find anything odd.
Please help me out.
Everything is in a single file named 
**index.php**

```
 <?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db = 'base64';

$dbconn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($db);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Base64 Encoder and Decoder</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="spinner"></div>
    <div class="template">
    <h1>Base 64 Encoder</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="#">
        <input type="text" name="encode">
        <input type="submit" name="encodebtn">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<br><br>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Base64 Encoder and Decoder</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Base 64 Decoder</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="decode">
    <input type="submit" name="decodebtn">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<br><br>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Result
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <?php
if (isset($_POST['decodebtn'])) {
    $text = $_POST['decode'];
    $decodehash = base64_decode($text); 
    $encodehash = base64_encode($text);
    echo "Decoded Successfully: " . $decodehash;
    $query = ("INSERT INTO hashes (Encoded, Decoded) VALUES ('$encodehash', '$decodehash')");
}
if (isset($_POST['encodebtn'])) {
    $text = $_POST['encode'];
    $encodehash = base64_encode($text);
    $decodehash = base64_decode($text); 
    echo "Encoded Successfully: " . $encodehash;

}

?>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.panel {
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
width: 40%;
}
.panel-primary {
border-color: lightgreen !important;
}
.panel-heading {
background: lightgreen !important;
}
```

Comment: SQL INJECTION ALERT - Read up on PDO with prepared statements

Comment: use `mysqli_*` function instead of  `mysql_*` function

Comment: voted as a typo; you never executed the query.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thanks its working now

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten

```
mysql_query($query,$dbcon);
```

keet it after the $query variable;

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this code

```
    <?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db = 'base64';

$dbconn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Base64 Encoder and Decoder</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="spinner"></div>
<div class="template">
    <h1>Base 64 Encoder</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="#">
        <input type="text" name="encode">
        <input type="submit" name="encodebtn">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<br><br>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Base64 Encoder and Decoder</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Base 64 Decoder</h1>
<form method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="decode">
    <input type="submit" name="decodebtn">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<br><br>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Result
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['decodebtn'])) {
            $text = $_POST['decode'];
            $decodehash = base64_decode($text);
            $encodehash = base64_encode($text);
            echo "Decoded Successfully: " . $decodehash;
            $query = ("INSERT INTO hashes (Encoded, Decoded) VALUES ('$encodehash','$decodehash')");
            $dbconn->query($query);
        }
        if (isset($_POST['encodebtn'])) {
            $text = $_POST['encode'];
            $encodehash = base64_encode($text);
            $decodehash = base64_decode($text);
            echo "Encoded Successfully: " . $encodehash;

        }

        ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<style>
    .panel {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        width: 40%;
    }
    .panel-primary {
        border-color: lightgreen !important;
    }
    .panel-heading {
        background: lightgreen !important;
    }
```